# Accented characters in array are not showing

Tags: php, arrays

I have some french words in a table and I want to display each of them character by character. However, when using `str_split` or any other way of converting the string into array (like `$string[$i]`), the accented characters are not showing at all.

On the other hand if I output the string directly, the accented characters are displaying correctly.

Example:

`echo "Québec"` outputs `Québec` (correct)

`str_split("Québec")` outputs `Q u   b e c` (issue)

The above indicates that it's not an encoding issue. I have also tried `htmlentities($string, 0, 'UTF-8')` in order to have HTML-safe characters but now when splitting html entities I get the following:

`str_split(htmlentities("Québec", 0, 'UTF-8'))` outputs `Q u & e a c u t e ; b e c` (issue)

How can I display each character separately but displaying accented characters correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation (http://php.net/str_split) , you could use str_split_unicode() built in the first example. The first example on the page refers to that.

Comment: I feel stupid for haven't noticed this function and I was searching for hours before posting my question. Thank you!